# How to access an object instantiated with the Flask app object outside of a view?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to authenticate calls to my Flask routes using the module [flask-hmac](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-HMAC/). It works for the routes defined where the app is created but I structured my code with blueprints and I don't know how to get the module in those files.
I suppose I have to use the hmac object instantiated when I create the app.
I thought I could pass it as an attribute of app like I do with my pool of database connections.

app_setup.py

```py
def create_app():
    app = Fask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(hmac_blueprint)
    app.hm = Hmac(app)
```

hmac_view.py

```py
from flask import current_app as app, Blueprint

blueprint = Blueprint('hmac_test', __name__)

@app.hm.check_hmac
@blueprint.route('/hmac')
def hmac_hello_world():
        return 'Hello World with HMAC'
```

I get
`RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`
I'm guessing this is because the app hasn't been created yet.

So I tried instantiating the Hmac object where i call create_app()

main.py

```py
app = create_app()
hm = Hmac(app)
```

hmac_view.py

```py
from .main import hm
```

Which gives me an ImportError

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'hm' from partially initialized module 'app.main' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

How to access to the hm object instantiated with the app to decorate a function ?

**EDIT :**
I managed to make it work. I'm new to Flask but that doesn't look like the right way to do this. Is there a more conventional way ?

hmac_view.py

```py
@blueprint.route("/hmac")
def hello_world_hmac():
    @app.hm.check_hmac
    def auth():
        return "Hello World with HMAC"
    return auth()
```

Comment: Have you tried [pushing the app context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/#manually-push-a-context)?

Comment: Yes and I got the same error.